# How to "unbreak" C code with "Artistic Style"

Tags: c, formatting, astyle

With [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) code formatter, how do I achieve the opposite of `--break-after-logical / -xL` such that if I have...

```
if (thisVariable1 == thatVariable1
        || thisVariable2 == thatVariable2
        || thisVariable3 == thatVariable3)
    ...
```

...I get...

```
if (thisVariable1 == thatVariable1 || thisVariable2 == thatVariable2 || thisVariable3 == thatVariable3)
    ...
```

Comment: @CloseVoter: If a code beautifier doesn't fall into the category of "tools used primarily for programming", then I don't know what possibly could.

Comment: From reading the documentation: possibly `--unpad-paren / -U`?

Comment: @Jongware just tried it and it did not work (nice idea though).

Comment: I browsed the doc for commands containing `merge` or `join` and it seems this beautifier doesn't merge existing lines at all. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jongware I guess multiline processing is beyond this beautifiers capabilities

Comment: Is your code editor capable of a decent GREP? In TextWrangler, this should work: `\s+(?=\|\|)`, replace with a single space. (Assuming your `\s` picks up newlines as well, I believe it does in TW.)

Comment: @Jongware yes I know I *could* do that --and thank you btw-- but I don't know whether I am ready to go down that road (ie. go through the entire C/C++ language specification)

Comment: Personally I'm in favor of multi-line stuff like this that improves readability.  However, in the spirit of answering the original question: you could remove all line breaks and re-format the code.  If you only want to change specific things: Clang (and probably gcc) can generate an abstract syntax tree for your code; you should be able to parse it to look for multi-line if statements.  Assuming Artistic Style supports it, just feed it the line range you want reformatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Artistic style` doesn't appear to make this possible.

That's quite sensible, since it actually obfuscates the code :

- Vertical alignment improve legibility by emphasizing identical pattern, and **distinct** patterns as well (a single `!=` would be harder to spot in a one-liner).
- It also eases diff tracking.

I would actually write :

```
if  (  thisVariable1   == thatVariable1
    || thisVariable2   == thatVariable2
    || longerVariable3 == thatVariable3 )
    ...
```